# my pycharm console is blank while printing tkinter code

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, console

this code should have given the input data i the console ,  but my pycharm console is blank without printing the input data also, it doesnt show any kind of error . see the code and help me solve this
i am a beiginner in python and this pycharm ide .help me

```
    from tkinter import *

    win = Tk()

    win.geometry("400x289")

    Label(win, text=" bhandari hotel ", font=" aeiral11 13 bold").grid(row=0, column=2)

    name = Label(win, text="name").grid(row=1, column=0)
    phone = Label(win, text="phone").grid(row=2, column=0)
    gender = Label(win, text="gender").grid(row=3, column=0)
    emergency = Label(win, text="emergency").grid(row=4, column=0)
    payment = Label(win, text="payment").grid(row=5, column=0)

    namevar = StringVar()
    phonevar = StringVar()
    gendervar = StringVar()
    emergencyvar = StringVar()
    paymentvar = StringVar()
    check = IntVar()

    namee = Entry(win, textvariable="namevar")
    namee.grid(row=1, column=3)

    phonee = Entry(win, textvariable="phonevar")
    phonee.grid(row=2, column=3)

    gendee = Entry(win, textvariable="gendervar")
    gendee.grid(row=3, column=3)

    emergencye = Entry(win, textvariable="emergencyvar")
    emergencye.grid(row=4, column=3)

    paymente = Entry(win, textvariable="paymentvar")
    paymente.grid(row=5, column=3)

    foodservice = Checkbutton(win, text='do you agree?', variable=check).grid(row=6, column=3)

    def amazing():
        print("hello"+ str(namevar.get()))

    Button(text="submit", bg='gold', command=amazing).grid()
    
    win.mainloop()
```

please help me solve this .

Comment: Please fix the indentation first

Comment: everything is right buddy , the code is 100% right . the console dont show any error but it doesnt print the input data . i only need help in that

Comment: What i mean is, try copy pasting this code you posted here and running it, youll see many errors

Comment: @CoolCloud remove 'enter code ' in enter "code herename = Label(win, text="name").grid(row=1, column=0) and you may not get the errors" line

Comment: I dont know if it isnt obvious, but `print(...)` will cause error either ways

Comment: The only thing that I can see there is to replace `amazing` implementation with:
    `print("hello"+ str(namee.get()))`

Comment: ...or, if you want to pass it to `Entry`, use `namee = Entry(win, textvariable=namevar)` (without the quotes ""), in which case you can keep your `amazing` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
namee = Entry(win, textvariable=namevar)
namee.grid(row=1, column=3)
phonee = Entry(win, textvariable=phonevar)
phonee.grid(row=2, column=3)
gendee = Entry(win, textvariable=gendervar)
gendee.grid(row=3, column=3)
emergencye = Entry(win, textvariable=emergencyvar)
emergencye.grid(row=4, column=3)
paymente = Entry(win, textvariable=paymentvar)
paymente.grid(row=5, column=3)
```

don't assign the variable in strings. here's the change.

**It's just a suggestion**
use :

```
a=Entry(..)
a.grid(..)
```

instead of

```
a=Entry(...).grid(...)
```

**whole modified code:**

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
win.geometry("400x289")

Label(win, text=" bhandari hotel ", font=" aeiral11 13 bold").grid(row=0, column=2)

name = Label(win, text="name").grid(row=1, column=0)
phone = Label(win, text="phone").grid(row=2, column=0)
gender = Label(win, text="gender").grid(row=3, column=0)
emergency = Label(win, text="emergency").grid(row=4, column=0)
payment = Label(win, text="payment").grid(row=5, column=0)


namevar = StringVar()
phonevar = StringVar()
gendervar = StringVar()
emergencyvar = StringVar()
paymentvar = StringVar()
check = IntVar()

namee = Entry(win, textvariable=namevar)
namee.grid(row=1, column=3)

phonee = Entry(win, textvariable=phonevar)
phonee.grid(row=2, column=3)

gendee = Entry(win, textvariable=gendervar)
gendee.grid(row=3, column=3)

emergencye = Entry(win, textvariable=emergencyvar)
emergencye.grid(row=4, column=3)

paymente = Entry(win, textvariable=paymentvar)
paymente.grid(row=5, column=3)

foodservice = Checkbutton(win, text='do you agree?', variable=check).grid(row=6, column=3)

def amazing():
    print("hello "+ str(namevar.get()))

Button(text="submit", bg='gold', command=amazing).grid()

win.mainloop()
```